# Get iBeacon proximity updates using CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I am trying to write an app that periodically receives updates about the proximity to the currently found iBeacons. I have two iBeacons that I would like to track, they are my own and I hardcoded the UUID for tracking into my code. The iBeacons themselves have the same major id but a different minor id. My question is about how to get periodic updates about the proximity to iBeacons found with a preset UUID. I get that this needs to be done with CLLocationManager, since this implements iBeacon ranging.

My current experimentation with CLLocationManager:

```
import UIKit;
import CoreLocation;
import HomeKit;

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, HMHomeManagerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

let homeManager = HMHomeManager();
let locationManager = CLLocationManager();
var beaconsInProximity: [CLBeacon] = [];
let beaconUUID: String = "11984894-7042-9801-839A-ADECCDFEDFF0";
let beaconMajor = 0x1;
let beaconMinor: [Int] = [0x1, 0x7];
let homeName = "Home";
var lamps = [HMAccessory]();
var lampNames = [String]();
var pickerNames = [String: HMAccessory]();
var selectedLamp: HMAccessory!;
var lightHome: HMHome!;
var firstLight: HMAccessory!;
var secondLight: HMAccessory!;
var thirdTestLight: HMAccessory!;
let beaconRegion: CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(uuidString:"11984894-7042-9801-839A-ADECCDFEDFF0")as! UUID, identifier: "Beaconons");

@IBOutlet weak var lampSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var configureLampButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lampPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var identifyLampButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lampSelectedLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lampStatusLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var beaconStatusLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if(selectedLamp != nil){
        updateLampLabel(selectedLamp);
        updateLampStatusLabel(selectedLamp);
    }else{
        updateLampLabelNoLamp();
        updateLampStatusLabelNoStatus();
    }
    homeManager.delegate = self;
    lampPicker.delegate = self;
    lampPicker.dataSource = self;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion);
    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion);
    locationManager.requestState(for: beaconRegion);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func homeManagerDidUpdateHomes(_ manager: HMHomeManager) {
    for home in homeManager.homes{
        for accessory in home.accessories{
            if(accessory.name.contains("lamp")){
                lamps.append(accessory);
                pickerNames[String(describing: accessory.services[1].characteristics[0].value)] = accessory;
                print("Added accessory " + String(describing: accessory.services[1].characteristics[0].value) + " to lamp list");
            }
        }
    }
    if(lamps.count != 0){
        for index in 0...(lamps.count - 1){
            lampNames.append(String(describing: lamps[index].services[1].characteristics[0].value));
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(_: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons: [CLBeacon], in: CLBeaconRegion){
    for beacon in didRangeBeacons{
        if(beacon.proximity == CLProximity.immediate){
            beaconsInProximity.append(beacon);
        }else{
            if(beaconsInProximity.contains(beacon)){
                for index in 0...beaconsInProximity.count{
                    if(beaconsInProximity[index] == beacon){
                        beaconsInProximity.remove(at: index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for beacon in beaconsInProximity{
        if(beacon.major.intValue == beaconMajor){
            if(beacon.minor.intValue == 0x3){
                if(selectedLamp != nil){
                    switchLamp(selectedLamp, true);
                    beaconStatusLabel.text = "region detected";
                }
            }else{
                if(selectedLamp != nil){
                    switchLamp(selectedLamp, false);
                    beaconStatusLabel.text = "lamping all the lamps that have ever lamped";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    let bRegion = region as! CLBeaconRegion;
    if(bRegion.proximityUUID == beaconRegion.proximityUUID){
        print("Correct region");
        beaconStatusLabel.text = "Entered beacon region";
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    let bRegion = region as! CLBeaconRegion;
    if(bRegion.proximityUUID == beaconRegion.proximityUUID){
        print("Exited correct region");
        beaconStatusLabel.text = "Beacon region left";
    }
}

@IBAction func configureLampButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject){
    if(pickerNames[lampNames[lampPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]] != nil){
        selectedLamp = pickerNames[lampNames[lampPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]];
    }
    if(selectedLamp != nil){
        updateLampLabel(selectedLamp);
        updateLampStatusLabel(selectedLamp);
    }else{
        updateLampLabelNoLamp();
        updateLampStatusLabelNoStatus();
    }

}

@IBAction func identifyLampButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject){
    if(selectedLamp != nil){
        identifyLamp(selectedLamp);
    }
}

@IBAction func lampSwitchFlipped(_ sender: AnyObject){
    if(selectedLamp != nil){
        switchLamp(selectedLamp, lampSwitch.isOn);
        updateLampStatusLabel(selectedLamp);
    }else{
        lampSwitch.setOn(!lampSwitch.isOn, animated: true);
        updateLampStatusLabelNoStatus();
    }
}

func updateLampLabelNoLamp(){
    lampSelectedLabel.text = "No lamp selected";
}

func updateLampLabel(_ lamp: HMAccessory){
    lampSelectedLabel.text = "Selected lamp: " + lamp.name;
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1;
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return lampNames.count;
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{
    return lampNames[row];
}

func booleanToInt(_ value: Bool) -> Int{
    if(value){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

func sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(_ message: String!){

}

func switchLamp(_ lamp: HMAccessory, _ value: Bool){
    lamp.services[1].characteristics[1].writeValue(booleanToInt(value), completionHandler: {
        error in
        if let error = error{
            print("Something went wrong! \(error)");
        }
    })
}

func identifyLamp(_ lamp: HMAccessory){
    lamp.services[0].characteristics[3].writeValue(1, completionHandler: {
        error in
        if let error = error{
            print("Something went wrong! \(error)");
        }
    })
}

func updateLampStatusLabel(_ lamp: HMAccessory){
    lampStatusLabel.text = "Lamp status: " + String(describing: selectedLamp.services[1].characteristics[1].value);
}

func updateLampStatusLabelNoStatus(){
    lampStatusLabel.text = "Select a lamp";
}
}
```

The goal of the app itself is to switch a lightbulb depending on if the user is nearby.

Comment: What is the question?  What is your code doing now?  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: You need to add `CLBeaconRegion` instances for the beacons you wish to monitor.  If the beacons can both be seen at the same time you will need to register two regions.

Comment: @davidgyoung I updated my question and changed the code to the contents of my entire FirstViewController.swift file. I have an iBeacon that I would like to get the proximity of as soon as it is detected. Once it is detected, I would like to get periodic updates about the proximity so that I know when to switch my light. I can not figure out how I would implement something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beacon.proximity field will be updated with each callback to `func locationManager(_: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons: [CLBeacon], in: CLBeaconRegion)`.  These callbacks will come once per second with an array of CLBeacon objects that have this field.  So every 1 second you will get an update.

Based on the way the code is set up, it appears that `beaconsInProximity` will be updated properly if the beacon is in immediate proximity and `switchLamp` will be called later in the callback method.

Understand, however, that the `CLBeacon`'s `proximity` field may not update as quickly as you'd like.  This field is derived from the `accuracy` field, which is a distance estimate in meters.  If the distance estimate is < 0.5 meters, then `accuracy` will be set to immediate.  If the distance estimate is > 0.5 meters, it will be set to another value.

The distance estimate in `accuracy` is based on a 20 second running average of the RSSI measurements.  Because of this, if you very quickly move from 5 meters away to right next to the beacon transmitter, the `accuracy` field will slowly change from ~5.0 to ~0.0 over the course of 20 seconds.  It will take nearly 20 seconds for the `proximity` field to show `immediate`.

Also, it is important to understand that the beacon must be calibrated properly with the measuredPower value set inside the beacon for as accurate distance estimates as possible.  If you are getting very inaccurate distance estimates in `accuracy` even after staying still for 20 seconds, then you may need to do this calibration.

Comment: When I try my setup, it looks like `func locationManager(_: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons: [CLBeacon], in: CLBeaconRegion)` is not even being called. I only get messages in the console for `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)` and `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion)`. It seems there is something wrong with my `if(beacon.proximity == CLProximity.immediate)` statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, wow, I think your callback method signature is incorrect.  Here is the proper signature for Swift 3.0: `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion)`

Comment: I changed my function to `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion)`, and `if(beacon.proximity == CLProximity.immediate)` still doesn't work. I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I do not know what fixed it, but after trying it today it worked. It works perfectly now.